# can you use Url.Content() in a master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i keep getting Compilation errors when i try to do this . .is there anyway to do this inside the site.master file?

Comment: It works. Can you post some sample code?

Comment: It really helps if you post the actual error messages when you ask a question on SO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the master page as an MVC master page?

The `Url` property that you'rew trying to use comes from the MVC framework's `ViewMasterPage` class.  If you added a regular master page, you need to make it inherit from `ViewMasterPage`. To do this, change the first line to

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

Comment: @IanCampbell: Yes; it doesn't.  `Url` comes from the MVC base type.  Use `ResolveUrl()`.