# Why does my Jquery Mobile web app lose its custom theme when I refresh the page

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, jquery-mobile

I'm writing a C# .Net MVC mobile web app with a custom theme built using the jQuery Mobile Themeroller.  The themes work fine, until I hit F5, click the browsers refresh button, or perform any other refresh action.  After a refresh, the page loses the custom theme and returns the the default jQuery Mobile css. I can only refresh the web app on the home page without losing he theme.

I've [read this short post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325988/ajax-call-for-jquery-mobile-pages-works-but-when-refreshing-loses-css-and-js-fun), but I'm not sure its the same. I can see how this would fix the styling after the ajax call is finished, but what about the refresh issue?  I mean, if I just hit 'refresh' or F5 on a JQM enabled page, it loses all of my custom themes (from themeroller).

Could this be because of the way JQM adds a `base` element to the first page?  I am not sure how to confirm this. I shouldn't have to call `$('#mypage').trigger('create');` on every document ready event, should I?

I appreciate any responses. I would love to post a jsfiddle but its difficult when using a custom theme.

**UPDATE**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/stylesheets/mobilere.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/stylesheets/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

This is everything in my `head` block - mobilere.min.css is my themerolled stylesheet.

I do not currently have a dom ready event setup because I wanted to avoid having to trigger a refresh on every page.

Comment: Can you post the code where you include the CSS style-sheet(s) and the code you refer to that you run on `document.ready`?

Comment: @Jasper, I do not currently have a `document.ready ` implemented, see update for stylesheet code and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to have the code you posted from the `<head>` section of your page in the `<head>` section of every page in the site, so if the user refreshes the browser on any page it will be accessible. This will not create much overhead when navigating around the site normally because jQuery Mobile only pulls in the first `data-role="page"` element on a page and adds it to the current DOM.
2. You should use absolute paths to the style-sheets so they can be found no matter what the base-url of the page is.

On a site-note, `$('#mypage').trigger('create');` is used to add the proper classes and HTML structure to the page widget, not change the style-sheet.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I am using a Master page for all of my pages, that is where those style/js declarations are held.  So they are on every page.  The absolute paths were not working because I accidentally used a Master Page, not an MVC Master Page - so my Url.Content("~/") calls were not working.  Fixed now with your help and this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285726/can-you-use-url-content-in-a-master-page